# Select the value of an element by name

Tags: javascript

How to access the value of this input field that is checked by its name attribute using Javascript :

```
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="1">
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="2">
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="3">
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="4">
```

I write this :

```
document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked').value;
```

but there is an error:

```
TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
```

And I do not want to be checked any inputs by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help you, but this snippet lets you select the value of the radio element that is checked, if it exists.

```
radioElems = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='rate']");
radioElems.forEach((elem) => {
    if (elem.checked) {
        console.log(`Check found with value ${elem.value}`);
    } else {
        console.log("Not checked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked').value;
```

Comment: Thanks @fraggley, but it was mistake in my writing

Answer (score 0):

you should call function for each radio button change event

```js
function handleRadioButtonChange() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked').value);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="1" onchange="handleRadioButtonChange()">
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="2" onchange="handleRadioButtonChange()">
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="3" onchange="handleRadioButtonChange()">
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="4" onchange="handleRadioButtonChange()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if any element matches your querySelector before accessing the value like this:

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked') && document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked').value
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a function every time the input change status changes using `onchange` this function, in turn, logs the value of the clicked input

```js
var rate = document.querySelectorAll(('input[name="rate"]'))

rate.forEach( each => (each.onchange = () => (console.log(each.value))))
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="1">
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="2">
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="3">
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="4">
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is absolutely correct! You just need to call this in `onchange` of the input. Since, you're calling this when no inputs are checked, you're getting this error.

```js
function handleChange1(){
console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked').value);

}
```

```html
<input type="radio" onchange="handleChange1();" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="1">
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="2">
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="3">
<input type="radio" class="radioButton" name="rate" value="4">
```